# In Swift, why can I not type-cast to a stored type?

Tags: swift, types, casting

I'm trying to do some things in Swift involving run-time checking of types that get erased due to storing as Any (which I know sounds ugly but it's a narrow use-case and I have good-ish reasons).  I ran into a weird problem that can be summed up with these examples:

This works under cli/REPL:

```swift
    let pType: Any.Type = Int.self
    if let x = 3 as? pType { print("found an int") }
```

However this does not work:

```swift
    let pType: Any.Type = Int.self; if let x = 3 as? pType { print("found an int") }
```

And results in **error: cannot find type 'pType' in scope**

When building as a program, I get the same error in either form.

Can anyone explain why this does not work?  And if there is any way around this?  And if what I'm doing is just plain wrong, why does it work in REPL?

Comment: "This works under cli/REPL" Well, it shouldn't. "And if what I'm doing is just plain wrong, why does it work in REPL?" It _is_ just plain wrong, but I cannot explain why it works in the REPL. There is something very odd about the scoping rules there that causes this sort of anomaly. If you try it in a real project you will discover that it doesn't compile, and that is correct. You cannot just define a metatype with `let` like that. This isn't Ruby or some wacky fun language like that. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is some kind of generic. Perhaps like this:

```
func isThisObject<T>(_ object:Any, ofThisType type: T.Type) -> Bool {
    return object is T
}
```

Examples:

```
let i : Any = 1
isThisObject(i, ofThisType:Int.self) // true
```

Or:

```
let s : Any = "Howdy"
isThisObject(s, ofThisType:Int.self) // false
```

Or you can omit the Any, it makes no difference.

---

Or, if actually doing the cast right there is important to you:

```
func tryToCast<T>(_ object:Any, toThisType type: T.Type) -> T? {
    return object as? T
}

tryToCast(1, toThisType: Int.self) // 1
tryToCast("howdy", toThisType: Int.self) // nil
```